# Ultimate Member: Redirecting after registration

Tags: plugins

I have been reading a couple of redirect after register threads with regards to Ultimate Member plugin and i have tried some of the solution but it didn't work.

The login and logout redirects work fine and as intended, but the register i presume is a little bugged as after I set a redirect url, www.example.com the redirect url becomes www.example.com/register/www.example.com

I have little knowledge with php and I am thinking it is a plugin code error?

Thank you in advance.

edit:

```
<?php

/**
 * Account automatically approved
 */
add_action('um_post_registration_approved_hook', 'um_post_registration_approved_hook', 10, 2);
function um_post_registration_approved_hook($user_id, $args){
    global $ultimatemember;

    um_fetch_user( $user_id );

    $ultimatemember->user->approve();
}

/**
 * Account needs email validation
 */
add_action('um_post_registration_checkmail_hook', 'um_post_registration_checkmail_hook', 10, 2);
function um_post_registration_checkmail_hook($user_id, $args){
    global $ultimatemember;

    um_fetch_user( $user_id );

    $ultimatemember->user->email_pending();
}

/**
 * Account needs admin review
 */
add_action('um_post_registration_pending_hook', 'um_post_registration_pending_hook', 10, 2);
function um_post_registration_pending_hook($user_id, $args){
    global $ultimatemember;

    um_fetch_user( $user_id );

    $ultimatemember->user->pending();

}

/**
 * Add user to wordpress
 */
add_action('um_add_user_frontend', 'um_add_user_frontend', 10);
function um_add_user_frontend($args){
    global $ultimatemember;

    unset( $args['user_id'] );

    extract($args);


    if ( isset( $username ) && !isset($args['user_login']) ) {
        $user_login = $username;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $first_name ) &&  ! empty( $last_name ) && ! isset( $user_login ) ) {

        if ( um_get_option('permalink_base') == 'name' ) {
            $user_login = rawurlencode( strtolower( str_replace(" ",".",$first_name." ".$last_name ) ) );
        }else if ( um_get_option('permalink_base') == 'name_dash' ) {
            $user_login = rawurlencode( strtolower( str_replace(" ","-",$first_name." ".$last_name ) ) );
        }else if ( um_get_option('permalink_base') == 'name_plus' ) {
            $user_login = strtolower( str_replace(" ","+",$first_name." ".$last_name ) );
        }else{
            $user_login = strtolower( str_replace(" ","",$first_name." ".$last_name ) );
        }

        // if full name exists
        $count = 1;
        while( username_exists( $user_login ) ) {
            $user_login .= $count;
            $count++;
        }
    }

    if( !isset( $user_login ) && isset( $user_email ) && $user_email )
    {
        $user_login = $user_email;
    }

    $unique_userID = $ultimatemember->query->count_users() + 1;

    if ( ! isset( $user_login ) ||  strlen( $user_login ) > 30 && ! is_email( $user_login ) ) {
        $user_login = 'user' . $unique_userID;
    }

    if ( isset( $username ) && is_email( $username ) ) {
        $user_email = $username;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $user_password ) ){
        $user_password = $ultimatemember->validation->generate( 8 );
    }


    if( ! isset( $user_email ) ) {
        $site_url = @$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $user_email = 'nobody' . $unique_userID . '@' . $site_url;
        $user_email = apply_filters("um_user_register_submitted__email", $user_email );
    }


    $creds['user_login'] = $user_login;
    $creds['user_password'] = $user_password;
    $creds['user_email'] = trim( $user_email );

    $args = apply_filters('um_add_user_frontend_submitted', $args );

    $args['submitted'] = array_merge( $args['submitted'], $creds);
    $args = array_merge($args, $creds);

    unset( $args['user_id'] );


    do_action('um_before_new_user_register', $args);

    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_login, $user_password, $user_email );

    do_action('um_after_new_user_register', $user_id, $args);

    return $user_id;
}

/**
 * After adding a new user
 */
add_action('um_after_new_user_register', 'um_after_new_user_register', 10, 2);
function um_after_new_user_register( $user_id, $args ){
    global $ultimatemember, $pagenow;
    extract( $args );

    um_fetch_user( $user_id );

    if ( !isset( $args['role'] ) ) {
        $role = um_get_option('default_role');
    }

    if ( $pagenow != 'user-new.php' && !array_key_exists( $role, $ultimatemember->query->get_roles( false, array('admin') ) ) ) {
        $role = um_get_option('default_role');
    }

    $ultimatemember->user->set_role( $role );

    $ultimatemember->user->set_registration_details( $args['submitted'] );

    $ultimatemember->user->set_last_login();

    do_action('um_new_user_registration_plain');

    do_action('um_post_registration_save', $user_id, $args);

    do_action('um_post_registration_listener', $user_id, $args);

    do_action('um_update_profile_full_name', $args );

    do_action('um_post_registration', $user_id, $args);

    if( ! is_admin() ){
        do_action('user_register', $user_id );
    }

}

/**
 * Update user's profile after registration
 */
add_action('um_post_registration_save', 'um_post_registration_save', 10, 2);
function um_post_registration_save( $user_id, $args ){
    global $ultimatemember;

    unset( $args['user_id'] );
    $args['_user_id'] = $user_id;
    $args['is_signup'] = 1;

    do_action('um_user_edit_profile', $args);

}

/**
 * Post-registration admin listener
 */
add_action('um_post_registration_listener', 'um_post_registration_listener', 10, 2);
function um_post_registration_listener( $user_id, $args ){
    global $ultimatemember;

    if ( um_user('status') != 'pending' ) {
        $ultimatemember->mail->send( um_admin_email(), 'notification_new_user', array('admin' => true ) );
    } else {
        $ultimatemember->mail->send( um_admin_email(), 'notification_review', array('admin' => true ) );
    }

}

/**
 * Post-registration procedure
 */
add_action('um_post_registration', 'um_post_registration', 10, 2);
function um_post_registration( $user_id, $args ){
    global $ultimatemember;
    unset(  $args['user_id'] );
    extract($args);

    $status = um_user('status');

    do_action("um_post_registration_global_hook", $user_id, $args);

    do_action("um_post_registration_{$status}_hook", $user_id, $args);

    if ( !is_admin() ) {

        do_action("track_{$status}_user_registration");

        // Priority redirect
        if ( isset( $args['redirect_to'] ) ) {
            exit( wp_redirect(  urldecode( $args['redirect_to'] ) ) );
        }

        if ( $status == 'approved' ) {

            $ultimatemember->user->auto_login( $user_id );
            $ultimatemember->permalinks->profile_url( true );

            do_action('um_registration_after_auto_login', $user_id );

            if ( um_user('auto_approve_act') == 'redirect_url' && um_user('auto_approve_url') !== '' ){
                exit( wp_redirect( um_user('auto_approve_url') ) );
            }
            if ( um_user('auto_approve_act') == 'redirect_profile' ){
                exit( wp_redirect( um_user_profile_url() ) );
            }

        }

        if ( $status != 'approved' ) {

            if ( um_user( $status . '_action' ) == 'redirect_url' && um_user( $status . '_url' ) != '' ) {
                exit( wp_redirect( um_user( $status . '_url' ) ) );
            }

            if ( um_user( $status . '_action' ) == 'show_message' && um_user( $status . '_message' ) != '' ) {

                $role_id = $ultimatemember->user->get_role_name( um_user('role'), true );
                $url  = $ultimatemember->permalinks->get_current_url();
                $url  = add_query_arg( 'message', esc_attr( $status ), $url );
                $url  = add_query_arg( 'um_role', esc_attr( $role_id ), $url );
                $url  = add_query_arg( 'um_form_id', esc_attr( $form_id ), $url );

                exit( wp_redirect( $url ) );
            }

        }

    }

}

/**
 * New user registration
 */
add_action('um_user_registration', 'um_user_registration', 10);
function um_user_registration($args){
    global $ultimatemember;

    unset( $args['user_id'] );
    do_action('um_add_user_frontend', $args);

}

/**
 * Form Processing
 */
add_action('um_submit_form_register', 'um_submit_form_register', 10);
function um_submit_form_register($args){
    global $ultimatemember;

    if ( !isset($ultimatemember->form->errors) ) do_action('um_user_registration', $args);

    do_action('um_user_registration_extra_hook', $args );

}

/**
 * Register user with predefined role in options
 */
add_action('um_after_register_fields', 'um_add_user_role');
function um_add_user_role( $args ){

    global $ultimatemember;

    if ( isset( $args['custom_fields']['role_select'] ) || isset( $args['custom_fields']['role_radio'] ) ) return;

    $use_global_settings = get_post_meta( $args['form_id'], '_um_register_use_globals', true);

    if (isset($args['role']) && !empty($args['role']) && $use_global_settings == 0 ) {
        $role = $args['role'];
    } else if( $use_global_settings == 1 ) {
        $role = um_get_option('default_role');
    }

    if( empty( $role ) ) return;

    $role = apply_filters('um_register_hidden_role_field', $role );
    if( $role ){
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="role" id="role" value="' . $role . '" />';
    }

}

/**
 * Show the submit button 
 */
add_action('um_after_register_fields', 'um_add_submit_button_to_register', 1000);
function um_add_submit_button_to_register($args){
    global $ultimatemember;

    // DO NOT add when reviewing user's details
    if ( isset( $ultimatemember->user->preview ) && $ultimatemember->user->preview == true && is_admin() ) return;

    $primary_btn_word = $args['primary_btn_word'];
    $primary_btn_word = apply_filters('um_register_form_button_one', $primary_btn_word, $args );

    $secondary_btn_word = $args['secondary_btn_word'];
    $secondary_btn_word = apply_filters('um_register_form_button_two', $secondary_btn_word, $args );

    $secondary_btn_url = ( isset( $args['secondary_btn_url'] ) && $args['secondary_btn_url'] ) ? $args['secondary_btn_url'] : um_get_core_page('login');
    $secondary_btn_url = apply_filters('um_register_form_button_two_url', $secondary_btn_url, $args );

    ?>

    <div class="um-col-alt">

        <?php if ( isset($args['secondary_btn']) && $args['secondary_btn'] != 0 ) { ?>

        <div class="um-left um-half"><input type="submit"  value="<?php echo __( $primary_btn_word,'ultimate-member'); ?>" class="um-button" id="um-submit-btn" /></div>
        <div class="um-right um-half"><a href="<?php echo $secondary_btn_url; ?>" class="um-button um-alt"><?php echo __( $secondary_btn_word,'ultimate-member'); ?></a></div>

        <?php } else { ?>

        <div class="um-center"><input type="submit" value="<?php echo __( $primary_btn_word,'ultimate-member'); ?>" class="um-button" id="um-submit-btn" /></div>

        <?php } ?>

        <div class="um-clear"></div>

    </div>

    <?php
}

/**
 * Show Fields
 */
add_action('um_main_register_fields', 'um_add_register_fields', 100);
function um_add_register_fields($args){
    global $ultimatemember;

    echo $ultimatemember->fields->display( 'register', $args );

}

/**
 * Set user gravatar with user_email
 */
add_action('user_register','um_user_register_generate_gravatar');
function um_user_register_generate_gravatar( $user_id ){
    global $ultimatemember;

    $ultimatemember->user->set_gravatar( $user_id );

}
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @PiyushRawat shared the code above in edit. Thank you.

Comment: this is the plugin code, have you modified this? or any redirection code in functions.php?

Comment: and where did you set the redirect URL?

Comment: I did not modify it nor any redirection code in functions.php i set the redirect url to the main page of my website. So basically, its like only open to some people and i want them to register before entering the page.

Comment: yes but where did you set the redirect URL?..is it in the plugin settings or a custom template??

Comment: can you try to set it as http://www.example.com instead of  www.example.com, i.e use http:// or https:// before the domain name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is related to URL protocols rather any bug in the plugin. Try to append http:// or https:// before your redirection url.

For more information look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997790/why-does-an-anchor-tags-href-values-need-http-preprended-to-the-url#answer-8997807) answer

Comment: @ProjectX.. mark the answer as accepted